# SourceTree showing different brances like they are in sync (when they aren't)

Tags: git, github, git-branch, atlassian-sourcetree

We're using SourceTree in a project with my friend, I'm on the master branch and he has his own branch (I know, playing on the master branch is not a good practice, but let's put this aside now), everyday I merge his branch into the master branch. Yesterday, he reset his branch back to a previous commit using the "hard" mode discarding all changes. From then on, our branches appear to be on the same "line" (as they are in sync, having the same content, whatever it's called). Before, the graph next to commits displayed correctly when we had differences, with two different branches in the line. Now, even though we have differences committed and fetched, we are both seeing this in SourceTree (we've restarted etc, no changes):

[image]

Why are different branches appearing to be on the same branch in graph? How can I solve this?

Comment: After the reset, did the remote version of his branch get deleted? He would be unable to push changes if this wasn't done, so you're seeing the remote version as it was before the reset.

Comment: @isherwood how do I test it?

Comment: Using the console: `git push origin :branch_name` (notice the colon). That will delete the remote.

Comment: Which branch is which? As I read it, `master` is your local one, which is in sync with `remote 'origin' master`. I assume `origin/ugur` is your friend's, which is one behind. SourceTree displays the status of each branch, so it makes sense that you both see the same. Also, where is Origin? Is it github, or is it your friend's repo?

Comment: @isherwood yes, it displays deleted: ` - [deleted]         ugur`. why would that happen? we never remember deleting anything consciously.

Comment: @GolezTrol master is the OK one, ugur is the reversed one.

Comment: Yes, you just now deleted it.

Comment: Maybe you both have activated the same branch?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like there's a divergence which is preventing push of the topic branch to the remote. If you watch the console output you'll see the the push fails.

When you do a reset, the remote needs to be updated as well. Often this is done simply by deleting it:

```
git push origin :branch_name
```

Then the developer can push the reset version of the topic branch:

```
git push origin branch_name
```

(or push with SourceTree).

*Note: Any other developers with a local copy of the branch also need to delete it. If anyone pushes back up, it needs to be deleted again.*

Now, after a pull, you both should see the correct branch structure.

Comment: After deleting his branch, he pushed his branch again to the remote, but still, they appear on the same line.

Comment: You will need to delete a local version of the branch also.

Comment: I deleted his local branch (I didn't use it anyway) from both local AND remote on my computer. I've deleted both the local branch and the remote (it was already deleted obviously on the remote, I got an error about that one, but anyway) at his computer, restarted SourceTree, without a trace of that branch on his and my computer. I've then recreated the branch, committed to it, pushed, and it still doesn't show the branch structure correctly.

Comment: Then there's something else going on. I'm out of ideas. :-)

Comment: Interestingly, it just went away by itself. I know it doesn't make ANY sense, but literally, I said 'f*ck off I'm losing time', and concenterated on coding. My friend also didn't touch SourceTree. I then went back to it was showing branches correctly.

Comment: Good to hear, though I'm inclined to believe doing the delete fixed it. Not sure why you weren't seeing results right away.

Comment: It also got fixed at my friend's computer too after a fetch. Interesting. Yeah, as a computer engineer, I also can't believe that it went away by itself, maybe it was just some bug with SourceTree..